# ASP .net current physical location

Tags: asp.net, xsl-fo

Hi I am developing an ASP.net web application. 
I need to find the current location (physical) of the web site (or the bin directory containing the assemblies).

I have tried using Directory.GetCurrentDirectory() and that returns me the ASP .net temporary directory.

I really don't like the idea of include an application setting for the absolute path in my config file (eww!)

Any help would be much appreciated! :)

Conclusion:

I should have given some context as to Why I would like the physical file path.
Thanks guys for your prompt responses to the question :)

I am using XSL-FO for .net (the [FO.net](http://www.codeplex.com/fonet) library) to generate a PDF.  Embedding images in FO requires an absolute path to be given:

```
<fo:external-graphic src="C:\MyWebsite\images\image1.jpg" />
```

What I needed to do was set the current directory to the web site (or bin directory), which would allow the XSL FO renderer to know where to find the image.

Answer (score 33, accepted):

You need `System.Web.HttpRuntime.BinDirectory` (physical path to the *bin* folder) and `System.Web.HttpRuntime.AppDomainAppPath` (physical path to the top-level ASP.NET application folder).

Answer (score 5):

It depends on exactly what you want to do with the path, but the usual approach is `Server.MapPath()`.  For example:

```
YourControl.src = Server.MapPath("~/images/image1.jpg");
```

That will return the physical path for the specified file.

Comment: Hi Rick, thanks MapPath is a handy method to be aware of, however it doesn't really fit in with my situation.  I am about to update my question with some more detail on why to give some context, sorry I should have done this in the first place.  Thanks for your help :)