# How to get the physical location of an ASP.NET web application without using HttpContext.Current?

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net-3.5, iis-7

I've found myself having a requirement to configure log4net based on a file relative to the physical location of the running ASP.NET web application. We like to start the logger as early as possible, so `Application_Start` seems a proper place. In IIS6, this works fine and has been running for ages, but now we moved to IIS7 and this won't work anymore:

```
string absolutePath = HttpContext.Current.Request.PhysicalApplicationPath;
```

because the HttpContext.Current is not available in many `global.asax` (Application, Session) events. This is old news, we all know it raises the now infamous [*Request is not available in this context* error](http://mvolo.com/blogs/serverside/archive/2007/11/10/Integrated-mode-Request-is-not-available-in-this-context-in-Application_5F00_Start.aspx). We don't want to move back to Classic Mode.

Now, the question is simple: without using `HttpContext`, is it possible to find the physical location of the currently running web application instance?

Comment: Will this help? - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1740422/asp-net-current-physical-location

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Try [**HttpRuntime.AppDomainAppPath**](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httpruntime.appdomainapppath.aspx). For more info, read [IIS7 Integrated mode: Request is not available in this context exception in Application_Start](http://mvolo.com/blogs/serverside/archive/2007/11/10/Integrated-mode-Request-is-not-available-in-this-context-in-Application_5F00_Start.aspx) posted by Mike Volodarsky.

Comment: That's what Mikael Svenson wrote. Apparently, I didn't read the my own link well, yours and mine are the same, lol. Just tested, works like a charm :)

Answer (score 0):

As an alternative answer to my own question, I'd like to add that `Server.MapPath()` works during the `Application_Start` event as well. The application domain path would then be equal to `Server.MapPath("~")`, but it's handier for mapping relative paths, removing the burden of concatenation (what MapPath was meant for to begin with).