# How to load a definition file at application start located in a virtual path

Tags: c#, asp.net

How do I load a definition file which contains some start up logic at Application_Start?

I only know the virtual path but not the server physical path. How do I convert the virtual path to server path without Server.MapPath()

I am not sure I can access httpcontext or not in the application start stage.

Thanks

Comment: You can access HttpContext on Application_Start. HttpContext.Current does the job.

Comment: @eugeneK: the depends on the version of IIS whether that works or not. See also this double: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3025984/how-to-get-the-physical-location-of-an-asp-net-web-application-without-using-http

Answer (score 0):

> *"I am not sure I can access httpcontext or not in the application start stage."*

You cannot use the `Request` object or anything from the `HttpContext` object in `Application_Start` [when you are using IIS7 or higher](http://mvolo.com/blogs/serverside/archive/2007/11/10/Integrated-mode-Request-is-not-available-in-this-context-in-Application_5F00_Start.aspx) (it does work with IIS6 though). However, getting the physical application path can simply be done with Server.MapPath as follows:

```
string physicalPath = Server.MapPath("~");
```

Not sure why you do not wish to use Server.MapPath, but it is a sure way of getting the location in a safe manner and it works well in `Application_Start`.

As you know now, you [cannot get the current context in Application_Start](http://mvolo.com/blogs/serverside/archive/2007/11/10/Integrated-mode-Request-is-not-available-in-this-context-in-Application_5F00_Start.aspx) as I said earlier, because there is not necessarily one. You can still use `Server.MapPath` as above, or, if you mustn't use Server.MapPath for some reason, you can use **[HttpRuntime.AppDomainPath](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httpruntime.appdomainapppath.aspx)** which works everywhere.

```
string physicalPath = HttpRuntime.AppDomainPath;
```

Answer (score 0):

I think there is a little misconception around the Application_Start method and the Global class itself.  A new instance of the Global class is created for every request, but the Application_Start method is only fired the first time the application runs.

You can actually access the HttpContext.Current.Server property from here just fine:

```
var server = HttpContext.Current.Server;
string path = server.MapPath(...);
```

Comment: This will not work with IIS7 and higher and `Application_Start`. It will work on IIS6.