# How do I get the root directory of my ASP.NET server application?

Tags: asp.net

In the start-up code (ie no request) of my ASP.NET application I need to get the path to the root of my app. I need this to open a file I have in a folder off the root directory.

How can I get this?

Answer (score 97, accepted):

```
Server.MapPath("~");
```

Will get you the root directory of the current application, as a path on the disk. E.g., `C:\inetpub\...`

Note that the `~` character can be used as part of web paths in ASP.NET controls as well, it'll fill in the URL to your application.

If your class doesn't have Server property, you can use static

```
HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath("~")
```

Comment: This caused a `NullReferenceException` as described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/6861368/197591). I think `HttpRuntime.AppDomainAppPath` is preferable as per [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6861451/197591) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3549729/197591) (read comments and go to the [link](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3025984/197591)).

Comment: I get "Server operation is not available in this context" when I try this.

Answer (score 45):

[HttpRuntime.AppDomainAppPath](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.web.httpruntime.appdomainapppath?view=netframework-4.7) is useful if you don't have a `HttpContext` available.

For example, a low-level library method to get a path relative to the current application, and it has to work whether it is a web app or not:

```
private static string GetDataFilePath() => HttpRuntime.AppDomainAppVirtualPath != null ?
    Path.Combine(HttpRuntime.AppDomainAppPath, "App_Data") :
    Path.GetDirectoryName(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().Location);
```

Comment: This is very useful when you cannot use HttpContext to get the Server object

Comment: This method returned what I was looking for: The root URL of my application running in IIS. Server.MapPath returns a file directory.

Comment: for efficiency change it to a static variable:  `private static string DataFilePath = HttpRuntime.AppDomainAppVirtualPath != null ?
    Path.Combine(HttpRuntime.AppDomainAppPath, "App_Data") :
    Path.GetDirectoryName(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().Location);`

Answer (score 7):

Another possibility is
[AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/674857/should-i-use-appdomain-currentdomain-basedirectory-or-system-environment-current)

Some additional ways:
[Different ways of getting Path](https://dailydotnettips.com/different-ways-of-getting-path/)

Comment: FYI the "Different way of getting Path" link (http://dailydotnettips.com/2013/10/29/different-ways-of-getting-path/) is broken.

Answer (score 4):

You can get this from Server.MapPath method.

Here is the MSDN Link:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms524632(v=vs.90).aspx