# Find a root directory of the web application

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc

I'm trying to find a root folder on the server. Nothing works, or works wrong

```
@{
        string [] list = Directory.GetFiles(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory());
        foreach(var item in list)
        {
            <p>@item</p>   
        }
    }
```

Shows exactly what I don't need

```
@{
        string [] list = Directory.GetFiles("~/");
        foreach(var item in list)
        {
            <p>@item</p>   
        }
```

}

Doesn't work

How to solve this?

Comment: I think that you are a little be confused.GetFiles method return some stuff alias string array of all files within a directory.What is your goal???

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I get the root directory of my ASP.NET server application?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17682843/how-do-i-get-the-root-directory-of-my-asp-net-server-application)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the following:

```
Server.MapPath("~");
```

The `~` is always the root in an ASP.NET application. If you insert it in a Razor view it will be translated to the appropriate path for "external access", e.g. `~/Content/site.css` will be converted to `/Content/site.css` if the site is hosted in the root directory or to e.g. `/Page1/Content/site.css` if it is hosted at a virtual directory called `Page1`. Therefor to get the absolute path you need to "map it".

If you do not have access to `Server` you can also use [`HostingEnvironment.ApplicationPhysicalPath`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.hosting.hostingenvironment.applicationphysicalpath%28v=vs.110%29.aspx).

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
Server.MapPath("~");
```

or:

```
HostingEnvironment.ApplicationPhysicalPath
```

Answer (score 0):

Refer http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178116.aspx.
For your ease i have modified your code:

```
string [] list = Directory.GetFiles(Server.MapPath("~"));
        StringBuilder sb=new StringBuilder();
        foreach (var item in list)
        {
            sb.Append(item + "\n");
        }

        Response.Write(sb);
```

Even though I am giving you answer, I will suggest try to have path which is configurable in web.config or in the database because fixing paths are like hard coding the login ID :). Hope you got me.

Thanks