# PHP $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] equivalent in C#

Tags: c#, php, document-root

I am converting a PHP code in c# and want to know what will be equivalent in c#.

I think I can use:

```
HttpContext.Current.Request.ServerVariables["PARAM"]
```

But not sure which "PARAM" need to use, below link has all param list :-

http://www.w3schools.com/asp/coll_servervariables.asp

Comment: it is `APPL_PHYSICAL_PATH` in asp

Comment: try this  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17682843/how-do-i-get-the-root-directory-of-my-asp-net-server-application

Comment: Are you talking about Classic ASP or ASP.NET? And if ASP.NET, which framework? MVC? Web Forms?

Comment: @jothi and @ Federico Dipuma thanks, but I need this in c# class library project. I mean its a MVC application and I need to get this in a class library project.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe use ASP MapPath Method ?

Doc : http://www.w3schools.com/asp/met_mappath.asp