# Set Page to redirect after login in aspx

Tags: c#, asp.net, redirect, authentication, membership-provider

I use a System.Web.Security.MembershipProvider to do my login-stuff on my aspx-Page.

My default page is stored in Pages/Default.aspx.

I defined this page as default page in iis. When I call my page via *server*/Pages/Default.aspx and do the login, everything works fine.

But when I call only *server* and do the login here, I'm redirected to *server*/Default.aspx (without the Pages-directory) -> which leads to an error, page not found...

Is there a way to prevent this, without changing the folderstructure of my project?

**EDIT:**

My Login-Control on the master-page:

```
<asp:Login ID="LoginBox" runat="server" Width="339px" DestinationPageUrl="/Pages/Default.aspx" FailureText="Username or password wrong!">
```

Comment: dont change the folder structure, instead change the url path mentioned in Response.Redirect() method

Comment: I'm not performing a Response.Redirect...
And the DestinationPageUrl is /Pages/Default.aspx (in my asp:Login -Control)

Comment: Try DestinationPageUrl="~/Pages/Default.aspx"

Comment: DestinationPageUrl="~/Pages/Default.aspx" brings the same result as before...

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to find the application context folder structure code on the aspx page,
please refer this :
[How to get the physical location of an ASP.NET web application without using HttpContext.Current?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3025984/how-to-get-the-physical-location-of-an-asp-net-web-application-without-using-htt)